# NSUserDefaults initWithSuiteName leaks memory in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, ios8

My project uses ARC.  The Leaks tool in Instruments is reporting that NSUserDefaults initWithSuiteName: leaks memory.

Has anyone else noticed this?

```
NSUserDefaults *theDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:self.myGroupNameStr];
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add any code or screenshot of that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this appears to be my own issue.

Unlike `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`, my own code must assume retain ownership of `[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.company.app"]`.

So the fix is to initialize self.myDefaults when my `UIInputViewController` loads, and then nil `self.myDefaults` in my `UIInputViewController`'s dealloc.

Comment: Can you explain why we should retain ownership of this object? It should be managed automatically as any other object under ARC. Maybe I'm missing something, this seems like a system bug...

Answer (score 2):

Create a singleton sharedManager for NSUserDefaults, and initialise the object once for the app cycle

```
+ (NSUserDefaults *)groupUserDefaults
{
    static NSUserDefaults *sharedGroupUserDefaults = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedGroupUserDefaults = [[self alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.company.appName"];        
    });
    return sharedGroupUserDefaults;
}
```

Comment: I think, this solutions looks standard. If it is singleton it can be accessed across all classes in a uniform manner. No need to write code for "NSUserDefaults" creation again.

Answer (score -5):

//**try this way**.//

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:AppDel.arrQueueForOffline forKey:@"Queued_Process"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: The OP explicitly talks about initWithSuiteName, not standardUserDefaults. initWithSuiteName is the only way to share data using User Defaults with the new iOS 8 extensions. Using standardUserDefaults if probably not a possibility.